# Rehosting Workflow 4 Designer adding foreach activity to toolbox

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I am using the designer rehosting samples and am trying to put the generic types into the toolbox, however I can't seem to make it work.

I've tried XAML based:

```
<sapt:ToolboxItemWrapper  AssemblyName="{StaticResource AssemblyName}">
    <sapt:ToolboxItemWrapper.ToolName>
        System.Activities.Statements.ForEach
    </sapt:ToolboxItemWrapper.ToolName>
</sapt:ToolboxItemWrapper>
```

and code based:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Activities.Statements.Foreach, System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
ToolboxItemWrapper w = new ToolboxItemWrapper(t);
category.Add(w);
```

however neither of them seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are leaving out what isn't working but I assume you can't add a child activity to the ForEach in the designer.

If that is the case that is because the [Body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647866(v=VS.100).aspx) property is an ActivityAction not an Activity and it needs to be initialized. There are several ways of doing this but the easiest is to get started with the [ForEachWithBodyFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee403155(VS.100).aspx) in the designer and drag that onto the design surface instead.

The following code works for me. I can drag the ForEach onto a workflow and add child items to it.

```
var cat = new ToolboxCategory("Standard Activities");
cat.Add(new ToolboxItemWrapper(typeof(ForEachWithBodyFactory<>)));
```

Comment: When I get the type of the generic activity, it gives me a null type (because it is generic and I am not specifying the generic type) The same applies if I use the ForEachWithBodyFactory.